# Copying files from one directory to another in SAS EG is not working

Tags: sas, copy

I am trying to copy files from one directory to another in SAS EG, but it was not working.

The basic idea in here is to convert .xlsm file to .xlsx file.

```
%sysexec( copy "&path.\excel1.xlsm"
               "&path.\excel1.xlsx" ) ;
```

I didn't get any error in SAS EG, but nothing happen (no file copied), does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Does your SAS session actually allow you to run operating system commands from SAS code?  Does the path actually exist on the machine where SAS is running (not the machine you are using to run the user interface called Enterprise Guide).

Comment: The path is valid macro variable. I am not sure how to tell whether I can run operating system commands in sas EG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your SAS session has the XMCD option turned on.

```
XCMD              Enables the X command in SAS.
```

You can use PROC OPTIONS or GETOPTION() function to see the current setting.  This option must be set when the session starts so you might need to modify the server you are connecting to with Enterprise Guide to one with the option turned on (or modify the configuration of the server).

Also make sure that the command and path you are using will work on the server where your SAS code is running.  You can look at some of the automatic macro variables like SYSSCP, SYSHOSTNAME and SYSHOSTINFO to see the operating system where SAS is running.

```
22    %put &=sysscp &=syshostname &=syshostinfolong ;
SYSSCP=WIN SYSHOSTNAME=XXXXXX SYSHOSTINFOLONG=X64_10PRO WIN 10.0.18362  Workstation
```

If you still have issues you can also use another method to run your command where you will be able to more easily see the messages that the operating system might generate.  For example using the PIPE filename engine.

```
data _null_;
  infile %sysfunc(quote(copy "&path.\excel1.xlsm" "&path.\excel1.xlsx" 2>&1)) pipe;
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, the file was copied successfully. It seems that the last section of codes worked, what I got from the system macro is below. '%put &=sysscp &=syshostname &=syshostinfolong ;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SYSHOSTINFOLONG resolves to X64_SRV16 WIN 10.0.14393  Server' What is the difference between Workstation and Server?

Comment: In addition to using Windows to manage your PC there is a Server version that can be used to run a multi-user environment.  Enterprise Guide is a tool for generating and running SAS code and collecting the outputs. It connects to a SAS server session to be able to run the SAS code.  So your SAS server session is running on a Windows Server machine.  Which probably is NOT the machine you are using to run the client application Enterprise Guide.  So be careful with paths you use in the SAS code that they are valid on the machine where SAS is running.